# Modules and classes in Ruby. Contradictions?

Tags: ruby, class, module

According to [RubyMonk section 8.1](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/35-modules/lessons/79-getting-modular) modules only hold behavior and not state and classes can hold behavior and state.

Yet modules are a super-class of classes in Ruby. How can this be?

Answer (score 4):

Oh brother, and if you forget about module/class instance variables and module/class methods, you can't even say that classes hold state--because it's the instances of classes that hold the state.  Classes hold a list of instance methods.  So that whole section on classes is technically wrong too.

The bottom line is that 99.99% of the things in ruby are objects, and any object can hold state.  A class is an object(as well as a producer of objects), a module is an object(but not a producer of objects), and instances of classes are objects.

I suggest you not worry about state.  Just concentrate on the fact that modules can be used for two things:

1) As a namespace:

```
module MyFunctions
  def MyFunctions.puts(str)  #...or: def self.puts(str)
    Kernel.puts "***" + str 
  end
end

puts 'hello'
MyFunctions.puts 'hello'

--output:--
hello
***hello
```

2) As a package of methods to be included, e.g. in a class:

```
module AnimalTricks
  def speak
    puts @noise
  end
end

class Dog
  include AnimalTricks

  def initialize
    @noise = "woof"
  end

end


class Mouse
  include AnimalTricks

  def initialize
    @noise = "sqeak"
  end

end

Dog.new.speak
Mouse.new.speak

--output:--
woof
sqeak
```

Comment: *Friend* I have one doubt. Would you help me ? I don't catch the difference between [File#ctime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-i-ctime) and [File#mtime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-i-mtime). could you help me ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Modules can have state, bru

```
module Foo

  @state = "a"

  def self.state
    @state
  end

  def self.stateful
    @state = "b"
  end

end
```

Look!

```
Foo.state    # a
Foo.stateful # b
Foo.state    # b
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you cited is really what that source says, then it lacks accuracy. Under accurate use of the terms, indeed that is contradiction.

However, people (inaccurately) use the term `Module` to mean "a `Module` that is not a `Class`". Under this sense, which is presumably what is meant, what is written there is not contradiction.